# Why ng-model is not binding input to variable from inside of directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <input test type="text"/><br/>
        myName1: {{myName}}

    </body>
</html>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('test',function($compile){
    return{
        terminal:true,
        priority:1000000,
        link:function($scope,$element){
            var cloned = $element.clone();
            cloned.removeAttr("test");
            cloned.attr("ng-model","myName1");
            var clonedElement = $compile(cloned)($scope);
            $element.after(clonedElement);
        }
    };
});
```

Though I have added `ng-model` attribute to `cloned` but when I type the value inside of input field it does not show up in the view, as it usually happens with ng-model. Why `ng-model` is not able to bind text I am typing to the `myName1`? What did I miss?

Comment: Why are you using {{myName}} instead of {{myName1}} ?

Comment: where you are checking? On plunker it is working fine.

Comment: Oh heck, it was just that simple, thanks.